# Fixing object initialization so an overriden method is called

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

What do I have (simplified version):

```
template<typename T> class Watcher
{
 public:
    T* m_watched { nullptr };
    Watcher() = default;
    Watcher(T* watched) : m_watched(watched) { m_watched->addWatcher(this); };
    virtual void notifyChange(int = 0) /*= 0*/{std::cout << "Watcher::notifyChange()\n";};
};

template<typename T> class Watchable
{
 public:
    std::vector<Watcher<T>*> m_watchers;
    virtual void addWatcher(Watcher<T>* watcher)
    {
        m_watchers.push_back(watcher);
        watcher->notifyChange();
    }
};

class Config : public Watchable<Config>
{
};

class Property : public Watcher<Config>
{
 public:
    Property(Config* config) : Watcher<Config>(config) {};

    void notifyChange(int = 0) override { std::cout << "Property::notifyChange()\n"; }
};
```

So when I create an instance of Property notifyChange() of the base class (Watcher) is called.

I understand why this happens, but I have no idea how to fix this still having proper modern C++ code (e.g. without making m_watched protected and so on).

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

During construction of the base, the derived sub-object doesn't exist yet.

You could try making a factory function instead, which takes control of creating `Property`s. Then it can instantiate in one step, and register in a second step. Make the factory function a `friend` as needed and have all the related machinery be otherwise `private`.

- [Vaguely related blog article](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/597)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I have chosen a bit different way with an `init()` method called both from `Watcher` and `Property` constructors.

Comment: @blackcat That's an anti-pattern. My suggestion was chosen deliberately. But, it's up to you.